# PHP syntax not working in localhost

Tags: php

I was trying to execute this piece of code

```
<?php
$number1=10;
echo number1;
?>
```

I am using XAMPP Server and notepad++ as the editor. I have saved the file as firstfile2.php in the htdocs folder that is stored in D drive. When i am running this file i am getting this code as the output and not 10.
Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: You've missed the `$` in front of `number1`. It should be `echo $number1;`

Comment: If you open the file in a web browser, you will get that code exactly as it is. To see it processed, you must have a web server running with PHP. Then, you must open the page through the web browser as in http://localhost/firstfile2.php

Comment: error is that instead of showing '10' as the output it is showing the code itself

Comment: What path are you using in your browser?

Comment: i tried giving echo $number1 but still it is showing the code. i am having the apache server running

Comment: file:///D:/XAMPP/htdocs/firstfile2.php

Comment: Looks like your server is not set up properly.

Comment: You're loading the file directly into the browser, not hitting your apache server... see Steven Martin's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the browser you need to navigate to   http://localhost/firstfile2.php
2. Make sure your file is not actually called firstfile2.php.txt because you didn't save it correctly
3. Make sure you have full php tags( short open tag `<?` is not enabled by default in some servers)